# Chef skip recipes

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe, chef-solo

I have 2 roles:

**base.json**

```
{
  "chef_type": "role",
  "default_attributes": {},
  "description": "Base Machine",
  "env_run_lists": {},
  "json_class": "Chef::Role",
  "name": "base",
  "override_attributes": {},
  "run_list": [
    "recipe[apt]",
    "recipe[clean-up]"
  ]
}
```

**web.json** which includes **base** role

```
  {
    "chef_type": "role",
    "default_attributes": {},
    "description": "Web Machine",
    "env_run_lists": {},
    "json_class": "Chef::Role",
    "name": "web",
    "override_attributes": {},
    "run_list": [
      "role[base]",
      "recipe[nginx]",
      "recipe[clean-up]"
    ]
  }
```

when I run, the run_list will be expanded as: **recipe[apt]**, **recipe[clean-up]**, **recipe[nginx]**. Note that it skipped the last **recipe[clean-up]** of the web role. Why is it? Is there anyway that I can force to rerun **recipe[clean-up]**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, Chef is a configuration management system, not a script runner.

Each recipe is supposed to be run once and get the system in a particular state.

This is done in many phases:

1. Sync the runlist (after expanding it, each recipe once in the order they appear)
2. Compile the resources in each recipe, making a resources collection (in order they appear too)
3. Converge: run the code for each resource (provider code) and do something if the desired state differ from the current state.
4. Run the delayed notifications triggered by updated resources.

More details [here](http://docs.chef.io/client/chef_client.html#the-chef-client-title-run)

The main idea is to decribe a system state, and be able to run N times not changing the system if it's in the desired state.

You can remove this recipe from your base role or you can do a "closing" role wich you ensure appear at the end of each node runlist.

Comment: thanks for your feedback, how do I do "closing" role that you mentioned?

Comment: As you did your base role, you'll have to ensure it's at the end yourself (there's knife plug-ins which can help for this)

Comment: ah.. ic. so if I add **recipe[clean-up]** to **web** role, then I need to remove **recipe[clean-up]** from **base** role. Am I correct?

Comment: According to your question, the recipe is already in your web-role. so just removing it from base would be enought (but without knowledge of the rest of your infrastructure I can't tell the impacts on other nodes)